# Matching to form a complete chain

Tags: probability

Say I have N things, for this example I'll use N=4 and we'll call them a, b, c and d. Imagine I assign one-way pairings such as:

a -> b,

b -> d,

d -> c

c -> a

In this case, you get a perfect chain where if you follow the one-way pairings you get one circular chain with all the items: a -> b -> d -> c and back to a
Another possible set of assignments that don't get you a complete chain:

a -> b,

b -> a,

c -> d,

d -> c

Let's assume that one item is never assigned twice. That js:

a -> b,

c -> b

Will never happen. What is the probability with N items that random assignment will result in a single complete chain.

Answer (score 0):

We don't mind what happens to the first number, thus we have $n$ options. Suppose $1\rightarrow k$. Then $k$ must be paired to anything that is not $1$, for which we have $n-1$ options. Continuing this proces we conclude that there are $n!$ different set of pairings that result in a complete chain.